# 実際のコードがない状態で必要なCPU/メモリの性能を検証したい

Tags: django, テスト

どんな性能のCPU・メモリが必要かを確認するための検証を行いたいのですが、
実際のコードがない状態でどうすれば確度の高い検証ができるのか、ご存知の方がいればお伺いしたいです。

### 背景

- 考えた構成で以下の非機能要求を満たすために、必要なCPUの性能やメモリの容量を見積もりたい

  - メモリの使用率 ピーク時でも30%以下
  - CPUの使用率 ピーク時20%以上50%未満
- 社の方針でクラウドは使わずオンプレミスでハードを用意するので、CPUやメモリの取り換えはあまり行いたくなく、最初に構築する段階でなるべく適切な性能を見積もりたい
- CPUの性能を確かめるために、「想定される一番CPUを使う負荷」をかけたい
- ただし、「想定される一番CPUを使う負荷」をかける際の処理のコードは現在外注しており、できるまで時間がかかる。
- ただインフラの構成を、スケジュールの関係上なる早で確定させたいので、コードがない状態でもなるべく確度の高い検証を行いたい。

今は想定される処理に似ている処理をGithubにあるプロジェクトから適当に引っ張ってくるしかないかなと考えているのですが、
「似ている」の妥当性をどう考えればいいのかも分かりませんし、そもそもどうやって見つけ出せばいいのかが分かりません。

どなたか同じような状況を経験がある方がいらっしゃいましたら、どう解決したかご教授いただけないでしょうか?

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: コードがないとして、OS、DB、ミドルウェアは決まってるんですか？

Comment: 検証したい問題は何でしょう？と思ったらタグがDjangoなんですね。通常のウェブサイトですか？

Comment: OSはUbuntu14.04、DBはMySQL、WebサーバにはApache、APサーバにはWSGI、フレームワークはDjangoを使用しています。
そうですね、検証したいのは通常のウェブサイトです。
すみません…色々情報が足らず

検証したいのはピーク時の負荷を再現して、その時のCPUのパフォーマンスから本番で使用するCPUのスペックを決めたいということです。
同時接続数が多く見積もっても200で、200ユーザがリクエストを1分間送りまくる間のパフォーマンスを見たいんですが、リクエストが来た際に具体的にどんな処理を行えばいいのか分からず困っている状況です。
（ただ、静的ファイルを返すだけならなんの負荷にもならないので）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

機能や画面が似てても処理コードの質で速度/負荷は何倍も変わってきます。したがってGithubから似てるプロジェクトを探してくるという行為にはあまり意味がなさそうです。あとサーバー合計何台を想定していますか？1台で何もかも処理しようと思うならなるべく最大サイズにしておいたほうがいいかと。CPUもメモリも積めるだけ積んでおくのをおすすめします。

Comment: 超雑な話でいうと、MySQL側で使うメモリは、想定されるデータ容量 < 搭載メモリ が一番わかりやすい基準になると思います。CPUは同時処理数/2のコア数があればいいかな。